# Riemann sums vs Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let us speak of the tagged partitions of an interval and a bounded function defined on it.

I think that the tags give rise to particular Riemann sums which may be quite different in value that the associated Darboux sums.

Is it really so or does some constraint exist between a Riemann sum and a Darboux sum depending only from the norm of the partition ?

Comment: See the answers to this question:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346129/one-epsilon-delta-statement-implies-the-other-darboux-integrability/353810#353810

Comment: For any specific partition, the Riemann sum is bounded below and above by the lower and upper Darboux sums.